# Xcode 6.1 stucks at downloading iOS 7.1 Simulator

Tags: ios7.1, xcode6.1

My Xcode 6.1 makes no progress with downloading the iOS 7.1. 
It takes even hours but nothing filling to the progress bar. I checked the download speed, it looks like the Xcode doesn't connect or download what it should.

How can I solve this issue? or is there a way to install iOS 7.1 simulator to Xcode with a *.dmg file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also have same problem with os x yosemite 10.10

My Solution is... updated my os to os x yosemite 10.10.1 then it all works fine for me.

Comment: Had the same problem with 10.10.1 and XCode 6.2. The solution was to upgrade to 10.10.2

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem with the latest updates to both Yosemite and Xcode (10.10.2 and 6.2 respectively).  Another bit of googling and I found that it was due to the laptop running off of battery power.

http://quabr.com/28380875/ios-7-1-simulator-not-downloading

Comment: Thanks for the help. How insanely un-obvious from Apple, seriously!

Comment: @DaGaMs, Glad I was able to help.  I spent at least an hour figuring that out.